# Error in getting the title for section

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data

I am creating an expense tracker kind of application.

My requirement is to get the date in the section header and the expenses added on that date in the table View. I tried the following code but its not working.

```
-(IBAction)bydate:(id)sender
{
[self.byDateArray removeAllObjects];
[self.byDateCountArray removeAllObjects];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
for(NSManagedObject *info in self.listOfExpenses){
    NSString *compareDates = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[info valueForKey:@"date"]];
    BOOL isAvail = NO;
    for (int i = 0; i<[self.byDateArray count]; i++){
        if([compareDates isEqualToString:[self.byDateArray objectAtIndex:i]])
        {
            isAvail = YES;
        }
    }
    if(!isAvail)
        [self.byDateArray addObject:compareDates];
}
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < [self.byDateArray count] ; i ++){
    NSString *compareDates = [self.byDateArray objectAtIndex:i];
    for(NSManagedObject *info in self.listOfExpenses){
        if([compareDates isEqualToString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[info valueForKey:@"date"]]])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    [self.byDateCountArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count]];
    count = 0;
}
self.byDateTab.hidden = NO;
self.byDateTab.frame = CGRectMake(0, 123, 320, 244);
[self.view addSubview:self.byDateTab];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
if(tableView == self.byDateTab)
    return [self.byDateArray count
 return 3;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
int rows;
 if(tableView == self.byDateTab)
     rows = [[self.byDateCountArray objectAtIndex:section] intValue];
return rows;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"]autorelease];
 if (tableView == self.byDateTab)
{
for(int i = 0; i < [self.byDateCountArray count];i++)
{
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        NSManagedObject *records = nil;
        records = [self.listOfExpenses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        self.firstLabel.text = [records valueForKey:@"category"];
        self.secondLabel.text = [records valueForKey:@"details"];

        NSString *amountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[records valueForKey:@"amount"]];
        self.thirdLabel.text = amountString;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == i)
    {
        int rowCount = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<indexPath.section; j++)
        {
            rowCount = rowCount + [[self.byDateCountArray objectAtIndex:j]intValue];
        }
        NSManagedObject *records = nil;
        records = [self.listOfExpenses objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row + rowCount) ];

        self.firstLabel.text = [records valueForKey:@"category"];
        self.secondLabel.text = [records valueForKey:@"details"];

        NSString *amountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[records valueForKey:@"amount"]];
        self.thirdLabel.text = amountString;
    }
}
}
```

But am getting the SIGABRT error in this line

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.byDateArray objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

I am getting the following error in the NSlog

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

Comment: at this point your array byDateArray is empty. Its clear in error log its says out of bounds apply break point or before using [self.byDateArray objectAtIndex:section];
log the count of byDateArray and the section or use brek point

Comment: i update my answer, have a look :) the problem is you have more than one tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is here

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if(tableView == self.byDateTab)
        return [self.byDateArray count];
     //why crashed at index 2,  because here is 3
     return 3;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.byDateArray objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

it crash at another tableview that not "self.byDateTab"

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView == self.byDateTab)
    {
        return [self.byDateArray objectAtIndex:section];
    }
    else
    {
         //you should deal with other tableview
         // it crashed here
    }
}
```

or just disable other tableview's section header

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if(tableView == self.byDateTab)
        return [self.byDateArray count];

    //i don't see other tableviews how to work, so if you do this, the code will work
    //then you should look back to the solution above
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error your `self.byDateArray` does not have any object at index 2 , so please check the contents of your array.

Comment: if i remove that method i am getting the records fine without any sections

Answer (score 0):

Your `byDateArray` seems to be empty.

What are doing with `[self.byDateArray removeAllObjects];`?

Comment: i have the other tableViews in which i am using the same array!.so i am emptying it.so,is that the reason y i am getting the error?

Comment: why are you returning `3` in `numberOfSectionsInTableView`. There is also `];` missing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the problem is in adding objects to you `self.byDateArray`
Maybe `self.byDateArray` is not initialized?
Please, make `NSLog(@"self.byDateArray: %@",self.byDateArray)` just before `[self.byDateArray removeAllObjects];` in your `-(IBAction)bydate:(id)sender` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is means a

`section`

value is bigger than

```
self.byDateArray
```

count.

Try add this in 1st code line:

```
NSLog(@" %@ ", self.byDateArray);
```

in -(NSString *)tableView: function for see a content of array.